# Combobox value (binded with an enum) in an instance

Tags: c#, combobox, enums

Good day lads!

I've got a question.

I think I'll be saving loads of text if you would see my form, so here we go!

**Form:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
    Held h1 = new Held("Tank", Lanes.Top);
    Held h2 = new Held("ADC", Lanes.Bot);
    Held h3 = new Held("Support", Lanes.Bot);
    listBox1.Items.Add(h1);
    listBox1.Items.Add(h2);
    listBox1.Items.Add(h3);
    */

    //Data koppelen
    cbRol.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Lanes));
}

private void btnAanmaken_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int getal;

    if (CheckEmptyFields())
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Vul alle velden in!");
    }
    else
    {
        if (CheckMovementSpeedIsInt(out getal))
        {
            string naamHero = tbNaamHero.Text;
            Lanes lane = ???
            int mSpeedHero = getal;
            Held nieuwHeld = new Held(naamHero, lane, getal);
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckMovementSpeedIsInt(out int getal)
{
    return Int32.TryParse(tbMoveSpeed.Text, out getal);
}

private bool CheckEmptyFields()
{
    return tbNaamHero.Text == null || tbMoveSpeed.Text == null || cbRol.SelectedItem == null;
}
```

**Held:**

```
class Held
{
    private string Naam;
    private Lanes Lane;
    int MSpeed;

    public Held(string aNaam, Lanes aLane, int aMSpeed)
    {
        this.Naam = aNaam;
        this.Lane = aLane;
        this.MSpeed = aMSpeed;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return this.Naam + " " + this.Lane.ToString();
    }

}
```

}

**Lanes:**

```
enum Lanes
{
    Top,
    Mid,
    Bot,
    Jungle
}
```

Alright! So as you can see I have combined the enum with the ComboBox. I'd like to put the selected value (when the user has pressed the button "Aanmaken/Create") in the instance.

How am I able to convert the object (from ComboBox) to a type (Lanes)?

If I haven't clarified enough, just give me a heads up!

PS: The "???" in the code is the place where I'm not sure what to put since that's the question hehe.

Comment: @ryanyuyu You're right, fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
Lanes lane = (Lanes)cbRol.SelectedIndex;
```

This works due to `enum` is typeof `int`, so your `Top` is actually `0`, and so on...

Comment: No Problem, that's the suppose `SO` is for :D

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your [`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxydatf9(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Lanes lange = (Lanes) Enum.Parse(typeof(Lanes), cbRol.SelectedItem.ToString(), true);
```

This also works for index

```
Lanes lange = (Lanes) Enum.Parse(typeof(Lanes), cbRol.SelectedIndex.ToString(), true);
```